# What is the correlation between Grade Point Average (GPA) and intelligence?

Tags: measurement, intelligence, iq, educational-psychology, correlation

- **What is an authoritative empirical estimate of the correlation between pscyhometric measures of intelligence and Grade Point Average (GPA)?**
- **What are the main factors that influence the size of the correlation? E.g., country, level of schooling (e.g., primary, secondary, university), method of GPA measurement, etc.**

Specifically, I'm interested in estimates derived ideally from meta-analyses. But estimates based on large sample studies would also be welcome.

Comment: Bear in mind it falls in "everyone's smart anyway" settings such as universities (especially at the postgraduate level) due to [SLODR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_factor_(psychometrics)#Spearman's_law_of_diminishing_returns).

Answer (score 3):

*Assessing Adolescent And Adult Intelligence* (Kaufman & Lichtenberger, 2005) goes through quite a bit of the research on this.  Or you can use the correlation of 0.7 that they report, which is based on an aggregation of more recent studies of adult intelligent test scores and academic achievement.  I don't see where they break down country, but they do look at level of schooling a bit.  Perhaps some of their sources will help.